# Package UIMA RUTA engine in a PEAR

Tags: uima, ruta

I have a "template project" created with the ruta maven archetype.For people working outside the workbench  I see that the maven option is the easiest, but I would like to know, Is it possible to package a ruta maven project to a PEAR file ?

I'ld like to know how should I approach the wordlists resources and descriptors.

Also, should I include the uima-ruta-core in the classpath of the PEAR ? (I ask cause the uima-core, for example, I add it as provided, so it isnt copied to the pear file).